# Convert pixel data to Bitmap int array- WP8 - C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, camera, windows-phone-8

I want to make an app that uses the camera , gets the frame from it, converts it and puts it over the screen. I found a tutorial from microsoft that does that with a conversion to grayscale, but i don't really need that. Instead i need that int array i got to be like from a 8b bitmap so my conversion function can work properly.So the main question is how can i convert that pixel data array to a bitmap array and then turn it back so i can display it to screen?Another solution would be to get directly the bitmap int array from camera, but how can i do that?

I need to work on the following code:

```
    void PumpARGBFrames()
    {
        // Create capture buffer.
        Width = (int)cam.PreviewResolution.Width;
        Height = (int)cam.PreviewResolution.Height;
        int[] ARGBPx = new int[Width * Height];

        try
        {
            PhotoCamera phCam = (PhotoCamera)cam;

            while (pumpARGBFrames)
            {
                pauseFramesEvent.WaitOne();

                phCam.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(ARGBPx);

                //here i need to do the conversion back and forward

                pauseFramesEvent.Reset();
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    ARGBPx.CopyTo(wb.Pixels, 0);
                    wb.Invalidate();

                    pauseFramesEvent.Set();
                });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                // Display error message.
                txtDebug.Text = e.Message;
            });
        }
    }
```

So,the fact is i don't need a bitmap , but an int array as a source of a 8b-bitmap.
The tutorial i got from microsoft is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202982%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i realised that the pixel data array was in fact an array of colors,that were in 32b.so i had to just convert a 32b color to a 8b one,not so hard as i thought.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

for (int i = 0; i < ARGBPx.Length; ++i)
{
    bmp.SetPixel(
        i % Width,
        i / Width,
        /* something to create a Color object from the pixel int value */
}
```

Comment: It seems that WP8 development doesn't support Bitmap.Only BitmapImage,but i can't use it as u said.

Comment: In that case you might have to just convert it into a 2 dimensional array and operate on it like that rather than a Bitmap.